# Python Import Error for dajaxice_config

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm experiencing problem regarding deployment of an already built application - the application is running on production server and I need to do some changes so I'm trying to deploy it in test environment.

After running:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I got message like everything is OK, server is running
but when I tried to access `ip_address:8000` I get following error:

```
ImportError at /

cannot import name dajaxice_config

     Request Method:   GET
      Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8000/
     Django Version:   1.6.2
     Exception Type:   ImportError
    Exception Value:
                       cannot import name dajaxice_config

   Exception Location: /var/www/etelavm/etela2/urls.py in <module>, line 3
   Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
     Python Version:   2.7.3
      Python Path:
                       ['/var/www/etelavm',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
                        '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
                        '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
                        '/var/www/etela.vm',
                        '/var/www/etela.vm/etela2']
```

If I try running `python manage.py shell` and tried:

```
import dajaxice
```

it is executed without any error.

Comment: Just copy paste `dajaxice` module to your projects root directory.

Comment: It is the name `dajaxice_config` that is the problem. Can you share the full traceback? The error message in your browser has a link to the text version of the traceback, click on that and copy that text into your question.

Comment: @Fledgling: *No!*, that is not the problem here!

Comment: @MartijnPieters due to security policy i shall not share full traceback... however can you please give me some ideas what can cause this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've not used dajaxice myself; a traceback would have told us where in your code the exception occurs. You can remove the base project path if that's what is sensitive, and / or rename your own modules to `foo`, `bar`, etc. Do you know what version of dajaxice you have installed? I see `dajaxice_config` was added in version 0.5, for example.